# quick factorization of rank-one matrices (generally, and of a particular form)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, rank-1-matrices

Let $Q$ be an arbitrary non-zero matrix and let $x$ be a column vector.

It should be true that $xx^TQ$ and $Qxx^T$ are both rank 1 matrices.

It is a fact that all rank-one matrices can be factorized as $uv^T$, where $u$ and $v$ are vectors. This can be accomplished by means of the singular value decomposition rather slowly. Is there a quick way to factorize the above rank-one matrices with small time complexity? I would think there should be a quick way to factorize all one-rank matrices...

Comment: If $Q$ is not square, you need different size vectors $x,y$ for $xx^TQ$ and for $Qyy^T$.

Comment: It is not true that $xx^TQ$ and $Qyy^T$ are always rank$~1$. Whenever $x\in\ker Q^T$ respectively $y\in\ker Q$ they are of rank$~0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But they are already factorized as wished. We have 
$$ xx^tQ = x(Q^tx)^t, \quad Qxx^t = (Qx)x^t. $$

Comment: D'oh! Why, of course. Thank you!